# Maven, Cucumber Junit runner class - upgrading dependencies causes `features = { "@target/rerun" }` failure

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

Trying to upgrade junit and cucumber (maven) to latest artifact. Previously was running v. 4.8.1. Upgrading to 7.11.1. Everything works except rerunning failed tests. I've looked everywhere and tried whatever I could, but can't get it to work.

The way it worked previously was for each feature test case run, a unique "txt" file would be generated in folder `@target/rerun`. Then the "re-run" class would go through each of the files in `@target/rerun` folder and re-run any failed Feature->scenarios.

Here's one original example of dozens of runner classes:

```
package com.postmedia.automation.step_definitions.runners.Cheetah.Search;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/main/resources/features/Cheetah/Search/SearchResultsSorting.feature" }, glue = {
        "com.postmedia.automation" }, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/SearchResultsSorting.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-reports/SearchResultsSorting.xml",
                "rerun:target/rerun/SearchResultsSorting.txt" }, monochrome = true)

public class Test_SearchResultsSorting {
}
```

Each runner class generates it own rerun file, so there's dozens of them in `target/rerun` folder.

Here's the re-runner class ***that worked with old versions***:

```
package com.postmedia.automation.step_definitions.runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true, dryRun = false, monochrome = true, features = { "@target/rerun/" }, glue = {
        "com.postmedia.automation" }, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/FailedScenarios.json" }

)

public class Test_FailedScenarios {
}
```

With new artifacts, running originals as is, got 2 errors:

1. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Couldn't create a file output stream for 'target/cucumber-reports'. Make sure the the file isn't a directory.`
2. `io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to parse 'target/rerun' Caused by: java.io.IOException: Is a directory`

I added `/cucumber.html` to all the runner classes and that fixed problem 1. I can't solve problem 2 ("isn't a directory").

I've tried:

- renaming rerun class to `Test_zzFailedScenarios` in case there was a problem with execution order
- changing the rerun filename in the runner class to `rerun:target/rerun/rerun.txt"`
  and then changing features line in re-runner class to `@target/rerun/rerun.txt`
  This is the closest I've come to getting it to work, but if there are more than 1 failed tests, only the last failed test appears in rerun.txt (getting over-written by subsequent tests??)

Other things I've tried:

- in re-runner class - changed features line in re-runner class:

  - `@target/rerun/.txt`
  - `@target/rerun/[Tt]xt`
  - `@target/rerun/*.txt`
  - changed the `.txt` extension to `.feature` in the runner class and then used `.feature`, `*.feature,` [Ff]eature.

Nothing works.
In summary, want the "re-runner" class to iterate through all the files in `@target/rerun` folder and re-run and failed scenarios.

I've also tried using `rerunFailingTestsCount=1` in surefire plugin. This reruns the failed tests, but I can't get both the first and second run to show in cucumber report (using `maven-cucumber-reporting v. 4.5.0`). If there's a way to get both runs in report using this, will do so.

If you need anything else (pom etc) let me know.

Thank in advance,

Comment: Interesting. Looks like this functionality was dropped somewhere along the line. I didn't even know it existed. Can you make an issue in the cucumber-jvm repo?

Comment: Thanks @M.P.Korstanje. I posted bug? in git repo here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2708

Comment: Also any possibility you know/can tell me latest version that still had this functionality? Would still like to upgrade to highest artifact I can, but can't without this.

Comment: You're on the highest version that supports scanning folders. Thanks for creating the issue.